# Interpreter ignores elif clause entirely

Tags: python, printing

The code in question is this:

```
age = input("How old are you?")

if ( int(age) ):
  print ( "Congratulations! Some people die before they get to be %s years old!" % (age) )

elif ( age < 12 ):

  print ( "You're way too young to hear all this swearin'. Get out." )

else:

  print ( "That's not how this works. That's not how any of this works." )
  raise SystemExit

print ( "You probably shouldn't brag, but that's quite a feat!" )
```

The `if` clause, seems to trigger fine, as does the "else" clause, which, if working as intended, ought to print the given message and close the program if the given input is anything other than a number. The problem is the `elif` clause, which the interpreter seems to just completely ignore. Even when I put 1, 2, 3 or 4 into the program - which is indisputably lower than 12 - it just continues on to print the "Congratulations!" line. I'm very confused and new to this - any insight would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Convert user input to `int()` before assigning to `age`. A very common error, indeed.

Comment: Please don't put extraneous parentheses around your conditions.

Comment: Also, please be judicious in your use of tags. For example, the `interpreter` tag should not have been used for this question, the "tag [interpreter] should be applied to questions concerning the programming of interpreters or for questions about the detailed inner workings of interpreters." This is a basic Python question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

I see, thank you very much for the advice - I'll be sure to heed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if int(age)`. What is this doing? It's just checking for a boolean value which is true. If it's true then it will always go into the `if` statement. In Python everything has a "truthiness" so any number which isn't equal to zero will result in the `if` being entered.

Here's something closer to what you're trying to achieve (I think?). You could edit to re-prompt for input, raise an error, whatever else.

```
age = input("How old are you? ")
if not age.isdigit():
    print("Invalid age, must be numeric")
elif int(age) < 12:
    print("You're way too young to hear all this swearin'. Get out.")
else:
    print("Congratulations! Some people die before they get to be %s years old!" % (age))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. What you've wrote definitely makes a lot more sense, thank you very much -- I'm still a little confused on the 'truthiness' aspect you've mentioned but I'm sure it's nothing that can't be rectified with additional reading and research. I highly appreciate the help, have a wonderful day!